# How to Run program one Process and some name only?

Tags: c#, process, single-instance

i create some project but when start App. How to Run this App one Process only and name much "test.exe" name only? when Lunch APP ?  C# 2.0

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get your question. Maybe http://translate.google.com can help you?

Comment: I think he meant a single-instance-only .NET application. Some sort of a singleton process.

Comment: The question isn't clear. Try to rephrase it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, not entirely sure what it is you are going for, but my interpretation:

If you want to ensure that only a single instance of your process is ever running at once, insert the following code at the beginning of your main method (in Program.cs).

```
if (Process.GetProcessesByName (Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName).Length > 1)
{

    //instance of the process already active, exit
    return;

}
```

You will need to include `using System.Diagnostics` at the top of your file.

Note that this is not a perfect solution, in that if a user starts two instances of the process at exactly the same time, then they will both probably close.

Comment: Or in the case of two different apps have the same process names.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample project which looks promising:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SingleInstanceAppMutex.aspx

I quote the goals here:

> Goal #1: Prevent a Second Instance
>   from Opening
>
> Goal #2: Activate the First Instance
>
> Goal #3. If the First Instance is
>   Minimized to the System Tray (aka
>   "Notification Area"), Restore It

Comment: @monkey_boys: After reading your question a few more times, I'm sort of confused what you actually want. Hah...

Comment: @o.k.w: after reading your answer, I think that you may have successfully interpreted the question. Not sure though.

Comment: source code very long and not useful can use Process class for check its?

Comment: @monkey_boys: That's one way though I doubt it's 100% foolproof.

Comment: @Fredrik: Yea, I think I got it (what the question meant). :)